# typescript: how do I overload a constructor?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to overload a class constructor, but I don't seem to get the concept. I keep getting `overload signature is not compatible with function implementation`

This is what I'm looking at:

```
interface IGeoJson {
  type: string,
  coordinates: [number,number]
}

abstract class GeoJson implements IGeoJson {

  constructor (public type: string, public coordinates: [number,number]) {}

  toJson() : string {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }
}

class GeoJsonPoint extends GeoJson {

  /**
   * err: overload signature is not compatible with function implementation
   */
//   constructor ( obj : IGeoJson);
  constructor ( obj : [number, number]) {
      let [longitude, latitude] = obj;
      if (longitude && latitude) {
         super("Point", [longitude, latitude]);
      } 
      else {
        let {type, coordinates} = obj;
        if (type && coordinates) {
            GeoJsonPoint.fromJson(obj);
        }
      }
  }

  static fromJson ( { type, coordinates } : IGeoJson) : GeoJsonPoint {
    if (type != 'Point') throw new Error("Error, expecting type=Point");
    let [longitude, latitude] = coordinates;
    return new GeoJsonPoint([longitude, latitude]);
  }
}





/**
 * runtime
 */

let here = new GeoJsonPoint([10.123,20.456]);
let hereAsJson = here.toJson();
console.log('here:' + hereAsJson);


let obj :IGeoJson = JSON.parse(hereAsJson);
let hereFromJson = GeoJsonPoint.fromJson(obj);
console.log('here From JSON.parse():' + hereFromJson.toJson())
```

I am trying to overload the constructor so I can do the following:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(hereAsJson);
let hereFromOverloadedConstructor = new GeoJsonPoint(obj);
console.log('here From overloaded constructor:' + hereFromOverloadedConstructor.toJson())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
constructor (obj : IGeoJson);
constructor (obj : [number, number]);
constructor(obj: any) {
    let [longitude, latitude] = obj;
    if (longitude && latitude) {
        super("Point", [longitude, latitude]);
    } else {
        let {type, coordinates} = obj;
        if (type && coordinates) {
            GeoJsonPoint.fromJson(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IGeoJson%20%7B%0A%09type%3A%20string%3B%0A%09coordinates%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20GeoJson%20implements%20IGeoJson%20%7B%0A%09constructor%20(public%20type%3A%20string%2C%20public%20coordinates%3A%20%5Bnumber%2Cnumber%5D)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%09toJson()%20%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20JSON.stringify(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GeoJsonPoint%20extends%20GeoJson%20%7B%0A%09constructor%20(obj%20%3A%20IGeoJson)%3B%0A%09constructor%20(obj%20%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%3B%0A%09constructor(obj%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D%20%3D%20obj%3B%0A%09%09if%20(longitude%20%26%26%20latitude)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09super(%22Point%22%2C%20%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09let%20%7Btype%2C%20coordinates%7D%20%3D%20obj%3B%0A%09%09%09if%20(type%20%26%26%20coordinates)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09GeoJsonPoint.fromJson(obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09static%20fromJson%20(%20%7B%20type%2C%20coordinates%20%7D%20%3A%20IGeoJson)%20%3A%20GeoJsonPoint%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(type%20!%3D%20'Point')%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Error%2C%20expecting%20type%3DPoint%22)%3B%0A%09%09let%20%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D%20%3D%20coordinates%3B%0A%09%09return%20new%20GeoJsonPoint(%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D))

But there's a problem with your code as you don't call `super` when you get a `IGeoJson` object.
Also, it can all be done like this:

```
constructor(obj: IGeoJson | [number, number]) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        super("Point", obj);
    } else {
        super(obj.type, obj.coordinates);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IGeoJson%20%7B%0A%09type%3A%20string%3B%0A%09coordinates%3A%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20GeoJson%20implements%20IGeoJson%20%7B%0A%09constructor%20(public%20type%3A%20string%2C%20public%20coordinates%3A%20%5Bnumber%2Cnumber%5D)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%09toJson()%20%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20JSON.stringify(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GeoJsonPoint%20extends%20GeoJson%20%7B%0A%09constructor(obj%3A%20IGeoJson%20%7C%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D)%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(obj%20instanceof%20Array)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09super(%22Point%22%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09super(obj.type%2C%20obj.coordinates)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09static%20fromJson%20(%20%7B%20type%2C%20coordinates%20%7D%20%3A%20IGeoJson)%20%3A%20GeoJsonPoint%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(type%20!%3D%20'Point')%20throw%20new%20Error(%22Error%2C%20expecting%20type%3DPoint%22)%3B%0A%09%09let%20%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D%20%3D%20coordinates%3B%0A%09%09return%20new%20GeoJsonPoint(%5Blongitude%2C%20latitude%5D)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D))

Comment: am I correct in asserting that I need the `constructor(obj: any)` as the last overload for it to compile?

Comment: Yes. You can read about [Overloads here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#Overloads), it's about functions but it's the same with constructors.

Comment: I read that at least 3 times, but it wasn't obvious to me until now. dooh!

Comment: You need to declare the different signatures without the implementation, and then you need the actual implementation (which comes at the end) to have a signature that matches all of the other signatures. That's the main point